# Domains and Exchange 2019

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, exchange

I've got a full domain environment at home and I've had my primary domain name for 13 years now and wanting to change it so it matches my exchange servers email domain.

For example; fyi those domain names are example not my real domain name.
All my domain computers and all my servers including exchange 2019 at home logon to "mydomain.com.au" and my email address is "yourdomain.com" which is hosted on my personal exchange server.  so my paid public domain name is "yourdomain.com"

What I want to do is re-domain everything to my email address domain of "yourdomain.com" I want to know if it's best practice to have everything as one domain name? and if so change an existing exchange server server domain be changed example below (email address stays the same).

From "exchange.mydomain.com.au" to "exchange.yourdomain.com"

Thanks

Comment: `1.` Domain rename with Exchange server isn't supported. `2.` There's no technical reason to do this. `3.` There's no practical reason to do this. `4.` Just add your "public" domain name as an accepted domain and set it as the Primary SMTP address in your email address policy. `5.` If so desired, add your "public" domain suffix as an additional UPN suffix and change the UPN suffix for all user accounts to this suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this Microsoft help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/configure-an-accepted-domain-within-your-exchange-organization-as-authoritative-exchange-2013-help) can asist.

You can use EAC to configure it.
Here are the detailed steps:

1. In the EAC, navigate to Mail flow > Accepted domains, and click Add .Add Icon.
2. In the Name field, enter the display name for the accepted domain. Each accepted domain for your organization must have a unique display name This may be different than the accepted domain. For example, the domain contoso.com could have a display name of Contoso Local Accepted Domain.
3. In the Accepted domain field, enter the accepted domain. Specify an SMTP namespace for which your organization accepts email messages. (for example, Contoso.com).
4. Select Authoritative domain. This option is for email relayed to servers within your Exchange organization for an accepted domain that hosts mailboxes for all the recipients within an SMTP namespace.
5. Click Save.